# Problems embedding a command in Bash PS1

Tags: command-line, bash, ps1

Hi all I am having problems trying to embed this command in my bash prompt so that it will update itself each time the prompt is shown. I would like it to be part of the prompt itself

`free -m | tr -s ' ' '\t' | grep Mem: | cut -f3`

Suggestions and ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Do you want it as part of the prompt, or do you just want it run each time the prompt is shown? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `PROMPT_COMMAND`, as @waltinator suggested, you could embed the command into the actual prompt with process substitution:

```
PS1='\u@\h\n$(showmem) \$ '
```

This PS1 is based on the one you mentioned in a comment, and uses the function that @waltinator made.

Comment: hi @wjandrea where would you suggest that I define the function showmen

Comment: In the .bashrc right before the PS1 definition, but it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 4):

What did you try? You could define a function in your `~/.bashrc`, thusly:

```
function showmem() {
    free -m | tr -s ' ' '\t' | grep Mem: | cut -f3
}
```

and then set Bash's `PROMPT_COMMAND` to that function

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=showmem
```

Remember to `source ~/.bashrc` whenever you change `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: +1 but why the function? Why not simply `PROMPT_COMMAND="free -m | tr -s ' ' '\t' | grep Mem: | cut -f3"` ?

Comment: I tried this `PS1='\u@\h\n $(free -m | tr -s ' ' '\t' | grep Mem: | cut -f3) \$'` in the command prompt to see if it worked but it threw this error  `t | grep Mem: | cut -f3) \$: command not found`. If possible, I would like to be able to embed the command in the PS1 value in the `~/.bashrc`.